# Could not find activesupport-3.2.9 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to deploying a Rails website via passenger+nginx. However, I got the error below when I try to visit the webpage.

These are the possible causes:
    There may be a syntax error in the application's code. Please check for such errors and fix them.
    A required library may not installed. Please install all libraries that this application requires.
    The application may not be properly configured. Please check whether all configuration files are written correctly, fix any incorrect configurations, and restart this application.
    A service that the application relies on (such as the database server or the Ferret search engine server) may not have been started. Please start that service.
    Further information about the error may have been written to the application's log file. Please check it in order to analyse the problem.

```
Error message:
**Could not find activesupport-3.2.9 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)**

Exception class:
PhusionPassenger::UnknownError
```

I ran *bundle install* in the website' folder and see all of the gems are installed successfully including activesupport-3.2.9, then I ran *rails server*, I'm able to visit the webiste via 3000 port. This should prove there's no critical bug of this website code.

```
Here is what I added to nginx.conf file:
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost "";
    root /var/www/mysite/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    }
```

I don't know what more I should check to solve this. Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try `bundle update`, just be careful if you have gems without specified versions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably need to configure `passenger.conf` to point to the same ruby version that you are using to run your bundler - try running the passenger config utility:

```
 passenger-config --ruby-command
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17088686/1578861